# What am I doing wrong with Sed

Tags: command-line, sed

My input:

```
sed -i 's/if ($.browser.msie)/if ($.browser={ msie: ( navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') ? true : false })/g' file.js
```

I have tried putting the search and the replace text in both single and double quotes, but it gives the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 79: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Insert whitespace before filename `file.js`.

Comment: There is a space before the filename, but inputing it here removed it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the single quotes around `Microsoft Internet Explorer` with double quotes and insert a space character before `file.js` as you mentioned in your comment that you already did. Also use a backslash character to escape the <kbd>$</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> characters by putting a backslash in front of them where they occur in the regex.

```
sed -i 's/if (\$\.browser\.msie)/if (\$\.browser={ msie: ( navigator\.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") ? true : false })/g' file.js
```

Comment: That works, and fortunately the code works with double rather than single quotes. How to get around it if the single quotes are required, example:  sed -i 's/$pathTo = '';/$pathTo ='/usr/local/bin/somewhere';/g' file.php  which gives the error: sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Use this command: `sed -i 's/\$pathTo = '\'\'';/\$pathTo ='\''\/usr\/local\/bin\/somewhere'\'';/g' file.php` Here's how it works: 1. Write the regex between single quotes. 2. Inside the regex use '\'' instead of a single quote. 3. Put a backslash before $.*/\^ (and also the 2 square bracket characters) and only those characters. For more information see [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script/33005#33005).